# EF 3.5 Circural dependency and other relations

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, self

Im creating my database model, and I have a tricky question:

[image]

When I try to save it:

```
public void InsertEntity(Paragraph paragraph, int templateId)
{
    paragraph.Template = Context.TemplateSet.First(t => t.Id == templateId);
    paragraph.Parent = Context.ParagraphSet.First(p => p.Id == paragraph.Parent.Id);    
    Context.AddToParagraphSet(paragraph);
    Save();             
}
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

but, when I remove this relation,

[image]

and save it, it saves perfectly.

```
public void InsertEntity(Paragraph paragraph, int templateId)
{
    paragraph.Parent = Context.ParagraphSet.First(p => p.Id == paragraph.Parent.Id);                        
    Context.AddToParagraphSet(paragraph);
    Save();             
}
```

Where's the catch ?

Comment: Does the self-referencing FK on Paragraphs include Template as one of the participating properties - if so wouldn't that be a circular reference (since you would have Template: 1->Many->Paragraph:1->Many->Template). Just a thought...

Comment: Ok fair answer. But looking at this guide on page 39 - https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=245ED00EDB4C374E&resid=245ED00EDB4C374E%21132&app=WordPdf the`re achieving a similar scenario with no problems so far...

Comment: Actually on P 39 it's showing a *Many-to-Many* relationship between the entities, whereas you have a *One-to-Many*. Many to Many is "automagically" handled for you by EF - maybe try changing that in your model :)

Comment: Whats stange i tired it before but it did not work. Must have mixed up the databases becous i have couple of connection string. Now it seems to work. Thanx anyway :)

Comment: Cool, glad it's working for you

Comment: this is odd - saving now owrks for the ralation many to many. And in the database data seems to liok fine. but when i load for example a template object from the Context it has no Paragraphs assigned - unlike the DB.

Comment: ok now i see it i need tu use the Include() method